# Domain name registered for client and they want to transfer it to another domain host. OK to charge them for the domain name?

Tags: domain-name

I am a freelance programmer and often I will register a domain name for a client under a domain name reseller (and of course under my account).

I wanted to know if there is any standard procedure for selling the domain name to the client or just let them transfer it.

Does anyone know a normal procedure for this type of scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the domain name was purchased on behalf of the client, then it belong to the client and I would not charge them if they want to move the domain to a different registrar.  It would not be ethical. I normally insert my name as technical contact only and leave the client as administrative contact, thereby indicating they are the owners.

Comment: thanks for the note. I rarely deal with this type of thing, so I appreciate the feedback.